# Why is Powershell not able to find my imported command after the first time the script is executed?

Tags: powershell

I have two Powershell scripts. Script A contains a simple Powershell function. Script B imports script A and then calls the function defined in script A. This works fine the first time script B is executed but on subsequent executions Powershell complains the the function defined in script A cannot be found. Adding -Force to the import-module call in script B seems to solve the problem but I'd like to understand why Powershell exhibits this unexpected behavior.

Here is script A.

```
function foo($param)
{
    Write-Host $param
}
```

Here is script B

```
Import-Module "C:\SomePath\scriptA.ps1"

Foo "hello"
```

I am calling the script from the PS command line:

```
.\scriptB.ps1
```

Here is the error I get the second and subsequent time that the script is executed.

[image]

Comment: not sure but might be related: http://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell+dot+sourcing

Comment: mind trying ". .\scriptB.ps1"? :)

Comment: `Import-Module` does not load module second time unless you use `-Force` switch.

Comment: That should work. It works for me. It could be that you already have a module with that name imported in your session (it won't re-import automatically). Try adding a -Force to the Import-Module command.

Comment: course youd have to remove and reimport or -force

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Script A isn't a powershell module (as it has a ps1) extention.  Instead, try dot-sourcing scriptA like this:

```
. c:\somepath\scripta.ps1
foo "hello"
```

Comment: cant ps1's be loaded like modules?

Comment: @JaquelineVanek Yes.  The problem here is that the scriptb is loading the module and when it exits, the module falls out of scope (even though a get-module shows it as loaded). I think the real answer is that loading that module from within the script is the problem. I'd suggest either dot-sourcing as mentioned or adding logic to scriptb to unload the module before exiting.

Answer (score 1):

k, i meant

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\joshua> cd .\Desktop
PS C:\Users\joshua\Desktop> .\scriptB.ps1
hello
PS C:\Users\joshua\Desktop> .\scriptB.ps1
Foo : The term 'Foo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\joshua\Desktop\scriptB.ps1:3 char:1
+ Foo "hello"
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Foo:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\joshua\Desktop> Get-Command -Module scriptA
PS C:\Users\joshua\Desktop> get-module scriptA

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     0.0        scriptA


PS C:\Users\joshua\Desktop> Remove-Module scriptA
PS C:\Users\joshua\Desktop> . .\scriptB.ps1
hello
PS C:\Users\joshua\Desktop> Get-Command -Module scriptA
PS C:\Users\joshua\Desktop> get-module scriptA

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     0.0        scriptA


PS C:\Users\joshua\Desktop>
```

seems that ps1's are loaded as modulues but whats going on with scoping? ;(

Comment: I didn't mark this is the accepted answer but thanks for pointing out that unloading the module allows it to be imported again.

Comment: heh, it aint an answer, just illustrating what i was thinking about. moreover PetSerAI pointed it out